# How to add a second player to this number guessing game for python?

Tags: python

Hi i am unsure on how to add a second player for this number guessing game whereby after player 1 makes a guess, then player 2 makes a guess. like between every guess. I am only able to make it so that the player 2 guesses after player 1 guesses finish all of his choices(code below) if anyone is able to tell me if what i am looking for is possible or if there is any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
def main():
    import random
    n = random.randint(1, 99)
    chances = 5
    guess = int(input("Player 1 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, you have 5 chances: "))
    while n != "guess":
        chances -=1
        if chances ==0:
            print("out of chances")
            break
        if guess < n:
            print("guess is low")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        elif guess > n:
            print ("guess is high")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        else:
            print("you guessed it")
            break
            
        import random
    n1 = random.randint(1, 99)
    chances1 = 0
    guess1 = int(input("Player 2 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, you have 5 chances "))
    while n1 != "guess":
        chances1 +=1
        if chances1 ==5:
            print("out of chances")
            break
        if guess1 < n1:
            print("guess is low")
            guess1 = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        elif guess > n1:
            print ("guess is high")
            guess1 = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        else:
            print("you guessed it")
            break
    retry=input("would you like to play again? (please choose either 'yes' or 'no')")
    if retry == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        print("Okay. have a nice day! :D ")
main()
```

Comment: Do you want player1 and player2 to play alternatively? So Player1 then Player2 then Player1, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this I would use a while loop and a variable to detect which players turn it is. Like this:

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 99)

player_chances = 5
current_player = 1

while player_chances > 0:
    if current_player == 1:
        guess = int(input("Player 1 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, {} chances left. ".format(player_chances)))
        
        player_chances -= 1
        current_player = 2
        
        if guess < random_number:
            print("->guess is too low")
        elif guess > random_number:
            print("->guess is too high")
        else:
            print("CONGRATULATIONS! You guessed it! Player 1 wins!")
            break
        
    else:
        guess = int(input("Player 2 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, {} chances left. ".format(player_chances)))

        player_chances -= 1
        current_player = 1
       
        if guess < random_number:
            print("->guess is too low")
        elif guess > random_number:
            print("->guess is too high")
        else:
            print("CONGRATULATIONS! You guessed it! Player 1 wins!")
            break

print("####")
print("Out of chances! The number was {}.".format(random_number))
print("####")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this possible in an efficient way I would have created a player class as such:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.getNumberOfTrys = 0
        self.guess = 0

    def getNumberOfTrys(self):
        return self.getNumberOfTrys

    def getPlayerName(self):
        return self.name

    def play(self):
        try:
            self.guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
            self.getNumberOfTrys+=1
            return self.guess
        except Exception as error: 
            print(error)
            return None
```

this class is responsible to create the player with the number of tries,his guess and his name.

the logic will be going through the list of players (you can add as much as you want) and perform the game logic as follows:

```
import random
p1 = Player("Player 1")
p2 = Player("Player 2")
players = []
players.append(p1)
players.append(p2)
n1 = random.randint(1, 99)
NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 5
print(n1)
while players:
    for player in players:
        print(player.getPlayerName() + " turn, you have " + str(NUMBER_OF_TRIES - player.getNumberOfTries) + " turns left")
        guess = player.play()
        if guess < n1:
            print("guess is low")
        elif guess > n1:
            print ("guess is high")
        else:
            print(player.getPlayerName()," you guessed it")
            players.clear()
            break
        if player.getNumberOfTries == NUMBER_OF_TRIES:
            print(player.getPlayerName(), " out of chances")
            players.remove(player)
```

Basically, create a list of players then go through each one and apply the game logic (getting input, comparing and checking number of tries)
after a player loses, we should remove him from the list and if a player wins we can clear the list and thus exiting the game.

Here is the full code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.getNumberOfTries = 0
        self.guess = 0

    def getNumberOfTries(self):
        return self.getNumberOfTries

    def getPlayerName(self):
        return self.name

    def play(self):
        try:
            self.guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
            self.getNumberOfTries+=1
            return self.guess
        except Exception as error: 
            print(error)
            return None


import random
p1 = Player("Player 1")
p2 = Player("Player 2")
players = []
players.append(p1) #addding player
players.append(p2)
n1 = random.randint(1, 99)
NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 5
print(n1) #for debug
while players:
    for player in players:
        print(player.getPlayerName() + " turn, you have " + str(NUMBER_OF_TRIES - player.getNumberOfTries) + " turns left")
        guess = player.play()
        if guess < n1:
            print("guess is low")
        elif guess > n1:
            print ("guess is high")
        else:
            print(player.getPlayerName()," you guessed it")
            players.clear() # exit game 
            break #exit loop 
        if player.getNumberOfTries == NUMBER_OF_TRIES:
            print(player.getPlayerName(), " out of chances")
            players.remove(player)
```

Hope I got your question right, and excuse me If there is any errors or typos, I just created something fast that you can be inspired by. I highly suggest you get into OOP, it very simple and it can make your life much easier :)

All the best!